# Displaying custom fields in a forum

Tags: 7, views, entities, nodes

I have made some custom fields at config->account settings (manage fields) and I have put them in my registration form but I want some of them display at image I show below under the post count and generally when they create a new topic or replay.

How do I display that field? From a search I did I found that it's inside the module VIEWS. I am searching inside there to find where to add the field.

http://img848.imageshack.us/img848/7913/costumfield.png

**Answer**
At drupal 7 at Configuration - account settings - right top cornet manage fields you can create custom fields and put them where you like, then the most common to do is to add these feilds in your code with editing the source code just i didnt know how to do it.. i dont thing there is another way..! because i use the module author pane and the best way is too add them to author panel in the module code..

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to take a look at http://drupal.org/project/author_pane. That shows author information as shown in the picture you have posted.

Comment: I know and i have author pane the thing is that probably i need to edit manual the module to have the field i need to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use Views and/or Advanced Forum modules to recreate your forum interface. http://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum

When you install Advanced Forum module, I believe it auto-generates some views displays which are designed specifically for the forum module.